# Ajax login with div refresh?

Tags: ajax, authentication

I am new to ajax and javascript, i want to replace my php/mysql login system using ajax so that my div's refresh if user is logged  in successfully without page redirection.

Comment: By page redirection, are you referring to the entire page or just the "page" content in your <div>s? I've implemented what you are talking about by using a `Location:` header on the pages being loaded via AJAX into my <div>s, that way the entire page doesn't get redirected, just the content.

Comment: just the page content. can you show me your example?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have content `<div id="login"></div>` and the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'login.php',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#login').html(data);
    }
});
```

Then in your login.php file:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) {
    header('Location: my_account.php'); //This is the page to show if user is logged in
    exit;
  }
?>
<form action="login_process.php" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

This way, when the client's request fires the ajax to load the div#login content, if the user is logged in already, the content loaded will be from the `my_account.php` page instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is incomplete...but thats the concept

```
$.post("login.php", { name: "John", pass: "1234" },
function(data) {
 alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 if (data == 'OK') {
   $('#divlogin').hide();
   $('#otherdiv').show();
 }
});
```

Comment: This would be suggesting that you are merely hiding content that is meant to be secured..